# Downloadable Japanese Dictionary

Tags: discussion

Wondering if there is a downloadable dictionary of the *data* for words and their translation/pronunciation, or at least a list similar to [HanziDB](http://hanzidb.org/character-list/by-frequency). Not looking for a PDF dictionary, but something that is more easily extractable into programming form.

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for a dictionary, the files of the WWWJDIC project are freely available: http://www.edrdg.org/wiki/index.php/JMdict-EDICT_Dictionary_Project

It is the basis for https://jisho.org/, rikaichan/rikaikun/rikaisama, etc. and certainly contains words and their translations, but as far as I know no frequency data.